# how can I view dot bit websites in Linux?

Tags: networking, firefox

I would like to browse .bit websites, using Firefox, or some other browser in Linux. How can I do this? I was looking at instructions on [FreespeachME](https://bit.namecoin.org/freespeechme.html), but the website says it is currently being rewritten.

can some one help me get dot bit domains as being recognized in Ubuntu?

Comment: Well, it seems the answer is pretty clearly on the site you linked to. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. It's an issue with new versions of Firefox removing APIs which the extension apparently required. Older versions of Firefox are known insecure. Your best options are to wait for the issues to be fixed in the extension, or if you must, you can probably grab an old Firefox version from the Firefox web site, and use it for those web sites.

Comment: @dobey: Could you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve .bit domains, you can add a new DNS entry on your system to use a provder the maps these domains.
[OpenNIC](https://www.opennicproject.org/) is one such provider.